# c++ map clear inside a map

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following typedefs

```
typedef map<string, IPAddressPolicyRulesInfo> SecondMap;

typedef map<string, SecondMap>   FirstMap;

FirstMap            CPCRF::m_mIMSI2PCRFInfo;
```

Within the c++ function:

within the function, i want to clear the 2nd map. Which is the best way to do this ? Any comments or suggestions are appreciated.

thanks
pdk

Comment: What you have now is much more understandable, thanks for editing. As for your actual question, you clearly already have an approach in mind, but the way you put in in your question, it's not valid. At the very least, you've got mismatched parentheses. But it's not entirely clear to me what your approach is, specifically: it's sort of halfway between two reasonable approaches I can think of, and I can't tell which of those you're looking at.

Comment: For posting here I would suggest using shorter/easier to read variable/type names.  To me `APN2PolicyRules` looks like jargen.  Perhaps something like `map1_t` or `InnerMapType`.

Comment: @hvd: What i meant is, in the map inside map, which is the best way to clear the 2nd map? The answer I provided might not be correct, but is just a clue to one of the ways it can be solved..

Comment: @ilent2 just edited as per your request. Hope this is more readable now

Comment: CPCRF::m_mIMSI2PCRFInfo.clear() if you wanted to clear the FirstMap (that is 2nd) or for (auto it=FirstMap.begin(); it!=FirstMap.end(); ++it) it->second.clear(); if you wanted to clear all the maps contained in FirstMap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this might get you started in the right direction:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

// In general you shouldn't use _t after your own types (some people don't like it)
// But for a post here it doesn't matter too much.

typedef std::map<int, double> map1_t;
typedef std::map<int, map1_t> map2_t;

typedef map2_t::iterator it_t;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Create the map
  map2_t m;

  // Add some entries
  { map1_t h; h[0] = 1.1; h[1] = 2.2; m[5] = h; }
  { map1_t h; h[0] = 5.2; h[8] = 7.2; m[1] = h; }

  // Output some information
  std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << m[5].size() << std::endl;

  // For each element in the outer map m
  for (it_t it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
  {
    // Assign a friendly name to the inner map
    map1_t& inner = it->second;

    // Clear the inner map
    inner.clear();
  }

  // Output some information (to show we have done something)
  std::cout << m.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << m[5].size() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Btw I was trying to search for a particular element in first map, clear a second map for which the passed key maps. Lets say for firstkey and secondkey